# java server pages converted to servlet?

Tags: jsp

i read that inside the webserver a jsp page is converted to a servlet. When does this conversion happen ? Do i have to run a specific command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done at runtime, when the JSP is invoked for the first time. Some web servers also come with a JSP compiler allowing to do that at build time, which has two advantages :

1. It allows detecting JSP syntax errors at build time rather than runtime
2. It avoids the first invocation time penalty (it takes some time compiling JSP to Java and then Java to bytecode).

Comment: my example test.jsp file is at Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\jsp\test.jsp i ran it once. where does tomcat create the servlet ?

Comment: It stored the generated class files in its *work* directory. The generated Java code is not stored anywhere unless you use the keepgenerated jasper option. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html for details

Answer (score 3):

A JSP page is automatically converted to a servlet at runtime when the JSP page is loaded for the first time.
On Apache TomCat server, when a JSP page is loaded you can see the autogenerated `.java` and `.class` files in the `\work` directory of the TomCat server.

---

If for example your `test.jsp` file is at
`\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\jsp\`
you can find the converted servlet (`.java` and `.class` files) at
`\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\work\Catalina\localhost\jsp\org\apache\jsp\`

Answer (score 1):

This is done automatically for you when the JSP page is requested so you do not have to run a command. Sometimes it is possible to pre-compile your JSPs and so on but it is not a requirement.

[This page](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro4.html) explains the lifecycle of the JSP page.