# Compiling Java Server Pages (JSP) in a WAR file to Class files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat7, javac

I have a test WAR file that I generated from source.  When I unzip the WAR file I see that the Java classes were compiled to .class files, but the .jsp files were not compiled.  I understand this is done at runtime and the .jsp files are eventually converted to .class files.

I developed my WAR file in Tomcat7.  I realize this is an odd question.  The end goal is to develop a static analysis tool which runs on class files (I cannot read jsp files).

I've read that I can optimize the WAR file and precompile the JSP files into a JAR file that is nested in the WAR file, but I can't figure out how to do it.  I'd like to find or create a utility that takes an unoptimized WAR file and generates the JSP class files.

Comment: `JSP`s are automatically converted to `Servlets`. See [How is a JSP page detected and converted to a Servlet by Tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892272/how-is-a-jsp-page-detected-and-converted-to-a-servlet-by-tomcat) and [java server pages converted to servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094905/java-server-pages-converted-to-servlet) for Tomcat-specific details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JSPs are normally generated on the fly. In Tomcat, it is done by the [Jasper JSP engine](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html).

It is possible to pre-compile them. This article might help: [How to pre-compile JSP](http://javapapers.com/jsp/how-to-pre-compile-jsp/)

It describes how to trigger the pre-compilation from the command line and includes an example Ant file.